# Propel2 ORM: How to implement Order By Field

Tags: orm, sql-order-by, propel

I use the Propel 2 ORM in my php webapplication and in a certain query I like to order my results by field.

```
$orderedIdArray = array(20, 10, 15, 30);
MyClassQuery::create()
    ->filterById($orderedIdArray, Criteria::IN)
    //->orderByField("Id", $orderedIdArray) --> method does not exist in Propel
    ->find();
```

I found a solution online to do this via Propel Criteria for the Peer Class. http://shout.setfive.com/2009/10/13/adding-order-by-field-to-propel-criterias/

However I want to do this with my Query Class. How would you implement the method in the Query Class?

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy&paste his code of `addOrderByField` into your `MyClassQuery` class and normally use it. There's no need to use `sfCriteria` in Propel 2.

Comment: I dont get it, how can I just copy this code? Query classes work differently thatn Criteria classes

Comment: Just add a orderByField method into your MyClassQuery class which contains code that accepts a field id. look into generated orderBy* methods to see which underlying method is used.